# C# How to query WebCam from WMI?

Tags: c#, usb, wmi

I use this query in WMI to get all usb devices:

```
SELECT * FROM Win32_USBControllerDevice
```

Result are serial items like this:

```
Antecedent: \\PC\root\cimv2:Win32_UsbController.DeviceID="PCI\VEN82......"
Dependent: \\PC\root\cimv2:Win32_UsbController.DeviceID="USB\\ROOT_HUB20..."
```

I want to find WebCam Device, but I cannot found any clue base on these items. I think I'm used a wrong way?

I don't want to use 3rd party such Aforge.net to do this just for listing WebCams, I want to use WMI only.

So, anyone would help me, please? thank you.

**[Problem Solved]**

use `SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity`

Comment: Very helpful of you to hand out the problem solution. Thanks